# Send e-mail to multiple CC and multiple TO recipients simultaneously using python

Tags: python, sendmail

Tried with only multiple to and multiple cc individually, which works fine but when i try both i get an error:

File

> "path\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\mypython\lib\smtplib.py",
>   line 870, in sendmail     senderrs[each] = (code, resp) TypeError:
>   unhashable type: 'list'"

Code:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication

strFrom = 'fasdf@dfs.com'

cc='abc.xyz@dfa.com, sdf.xciv@lfk.com'

to='sadf@sdfa.com,123.lfadf@fa.com'

msg = MIMEMultipart('related')
msg['Subject'] = 'Subject'
msg['From'] = strFrom
msg['To'] =to
msg['Cc']=cc

#msg['Bcc']= strBcc

msg.preamble = 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.'


msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg.attach(msgAlternative)

msgText = MIMEText('This is the alternative plain text message.')
msgAlternative.attach(msgText)


msgText = MIMEText('''<html>

<body><p>Hello<p>
        </body>
        </html> '''.format(**locals()), 'html')
msgAlternative.attach(msgText)



import smtplib
smtp = smtplib.SMTP()
smtp.connect('smtp address')
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.sendmail(strFrom, to, msg.as_string())
smtp.quit()
```

Comment: Please post the calling code.

Comment: If you can't put anything useful in the `text/plain` part, maybe you should not be producing `multipart/alternative` at all. (I know some people do this as an empty gesture towards some spam filters which require this, but you are really doing your recipients a disservice by sending them junk.)

Answer (score 7):

Attaching `To` or `from` should be a string and sendmail should always be in the form of the list.

```
cc=['abc.xyz@dfa.com', 'sdf.xciv@lfk.com']

to=['sadf@sdfa.com','123.lfadf@fa.com']

msg['To'] =','.join(to)

msg['Cc']=','.join(cc)   

toAddress = to + cc    

smtp.sendmail(strFrom, toAddress, msg.as_string())
```

Comment: @GufranHasan can you please tell me reason for downvote so i would improve my answer??

Comment: I didn't downvote dear. Just I edit your post for users attraction.

Answer (score 4):

The `to` parameter should be a list of all the addresses you wish to send the message to.  The division in `To:` and `Cc:` is basically for display purposes only; SMTP simply has a single sequence of recipients which translate to one `RCPT TO` command for each address.

```
def addresses(addrstring):
    """Split in comma, strip surrounding whitespace."""
    return [x.strip() for x in addrstring.split(',')]

smtp.sendmail(strFrom, addresses(to) + addresses(cc), msg.as_string())
```