# Python Sendgrid add CC to email

Tags: python, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid for Python. I want to CC some people in an email. It seems like they may no longer support CC'ing on emails, though I'm not positive if that's true? But surely there is a work around to it somehow, but I am surprised I can't find much support on this.

Here is my basic code:

```
sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey='*****')
from_email = Email(sender_address, sender_name)
to_email = Email(email_address)
subject = subject
content = Content("text/plain", email_message)
mail = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
```

How can I modify this so it will CC someone on an email?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I resolved it. Santiago's answer got me mostly there, but here is what I needed to do:

```
sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey='****')
from_email = Email(sender_address, sender_name)
to_email = Email(to_email)
cc_email = Email(cc_email)
p = Personalization()
p.add_to(to_email)
p.add_cc(cc_email)
subject = subject
content = Content("text/plain", email_message)
mail = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
mail.add_personalization(p)
response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
```

If you don't include the p.add_to(to_email) it rejects it because there is no "to email" in the personalization object. Also, if you don't include the "to_email" inside the mail object it rejects it because it is looking for that argument, so you have to be a bit redundant and define it twice.

Comment: The `Email` object usage demonstrated here was what I needed for my task. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 11):

Using the SendGrid's `Personalization()` or `Email()` class did not work for me. This is how I got it to work:

```
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail, Cc

# using a list of tuples for emails
# e.g. [('email1@example.com', 'email1@example.com'),('email2@example.com', 'email2@example.com')]
to_emails = []
for r in recipients:
  to_emails.append((r, r))

# note the Cc class
cc_emails = []
for c in cc:
  cc_emails.append(Cc(c, c))

message = Mail(
  from_email=from_email,
  to_emails=to_emails,
  subject='My Subject',
  html_content=f'<div>My HTML Email...</div>'
)

if cc_emails:
  message.add_cc(cc_emails)

try:
  sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))            
  sg.send(message)  
except Exception as e:            
  print(f'{e}')
```

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking at the code: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/examples/mail/mail.py

And it looks like you can do that by adding a personalization to the mail, for example:

```
cc_email = Email(cc_address)
p = Personalization()
p.add_cc(cc_email)
mail.add_personalization(p)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, this gives me the following error: 

python_http_client.exceptions.BadRequestsError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Comment: If I use "p.add_to" instead of "p.add_cc" it does work, however, it sends them emails individually. I'd like for them to be included on the email chain so if they reply all, it goes to everyone.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what what could be happening. At that point it would be good to see the HTTP request and response to see if there is anything wrong there.

Comment: It is strange because according to the documentation, it should work... My JSON body looks just like the JSON object they have in this documentation: https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/personalizations/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49062924/send-e-mail-to-multiple-cc-and-multiple-to-recipients-simultaneously-using-pytho) you can CC to email if you add another email to 'to_email'.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't using SendGrid.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cc multiple user then in djanogo using sendgrid you need to import the below line
[image]

the function that will be used to send the mail
[image]

and finally how you ned to send the data paramters to the above function so that it can CC the person

```
email = send_sandgridmail(sender=sender,receiver=receivers,subject=subject,content=message,reply_to=sender,cc=[admin_mail_account_mail,"rawatanup918@gmail.com"],attachment=None)
```

Comment: Instead of posting screencaps of code, could you paste the code directly into your answer? This helps our sight-impaired community members to understand your answer if they're browsing using a screen-reader.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this'll help.simplified from @anurag image script

```
import os
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import To,Mail,ReplyTo,Email,Cc
def send_sandgridmail (sender, receiver, subject, content, reply_to=None, cc=[], attachment=None) :
    # content = convert_safe_text(content)
    # to email = To(receiver)
    message = Mail(
        from_email=str(sender),
        to_emails=receiver,
        subject= str(subject),
        html_content = content)

    if reply_to:
        message.reply_to= ReplyTo(reply_to)

    if attachment:
        message.add_attachment (attachment)

    if len(cc):
        cc_mail = [] 
        for cc_person in cc:
            cc_mail.append(Cc(cc_person, cc_person)) 
        message.add_cc (cc_mail)

    try:
        SENDGRID_API_KEY = 'your sendgrid api key'
        sg= SendGridAPIClient (SENDGRID_API_KEY)
        response= sg.send(message)
        print (response.status_code)
        # print (response.body)
        # print (response.headers)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return response
```